# Azure B2C Authentication without user

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-3.0

We use an Azure AD B2C Api. The user authentication via Angular Frontend works fine.
Now, we created a separate BackgroundService project (.net core 3.0) that needs to access the api, too. The service runs without a user authentication.
In a standard Azure AD Api I would authenticate the service by using ClientId and Secret.

How can I authenticate the service against the B2C Api without user authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Client credential flow is not currently supported by Azure AD B2C. See [Current limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-apps#current-limitations).

It seems that the article is not very clear and confuses some customers. But the author has provided more details in the [answer](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/5100#issuecomment-377285823).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a code example that demonstrates the workaround?

Comment: Yes, see my sample: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/apps/tree/master/spa/javascript-hellojs-singlepageapp/source-code/.Net-Core-API-RBAC/MultiBearerAPI